# "apt-get" ruined after a failed PPA addition. How do I fix this?

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, ppa

I was trying to xdman from the nooblabs PPA however something just went wrong now `apt-get is ruined. Here's what I get when I try to run the update manager:

[image: update-manager]

Also when I try to correct the error (as directed by synaptic package manager), I get this message:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: The package oracle-java8-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

How can I rectify this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going through a series of commands

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I am going to guess the first 2 will fail.

Next run

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all oracle-java8-installer
```

If that command fails you have to manually remove

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm oracle-java8-installer*
```

Then again

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq oracle-java8-installer
```

Should work now.

See : http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: Thank you so much. The 'next run' command worked like magic